# How to select into a variable in SQL when the result might be null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE NewSeqType(IN mySubschemaID INT, IN hashVal bigint(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE newSeqTypeID INT;
    SELECT MAX(ID)+1 INTO newSeqTypeID FROM sequenceType WHERE subschemaID=mySubschemaID;
    INSERT INTO SequenceType(ID, HashValue, subschemaID) VALUES(newSeqTypeID, hashVal, mySubschemaID);
  SELECT  LAST_INSERT_ID() as ID; -- return prim key
END//
```

This works when there is already data in the table where `subschemaID=mySubschemaID`, but if that SELECT statement returns `null`, then the `MAX(ID)+1` part gives the error `column ID cannot be null`.

How can I give ID a default value, say 0, in that case?

Comment: I am guessing that this is MySQL based on the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT coalesce(MAX(ID)+1, 1) INTO newSeqTypeID FROM sequenceType WHERE subschemaID=mySubschemaID;

INSERT INTO SequenceType(ID, HashValue, subschemaID) VALUES(newSeqTypeID, hashVal, mySubschemaID);
```

Often, this type of work is done in a before insert trigger, to keep the values aligned.